# Is there any sort of 'default' variable in R, like in Perl?

Tags: r, function, variables, select, default

So, I want to select some values out of a vector based on their output from a certain function.

Where, for example:

```
RES <- c("CTSD_1", "CTSD_2", "ARID3A")
RE <- RES[1]
strhead(RE, -2)
```

Would return "CTSD"

Now, what I want to do is something along these lines:

```
RES[strhead($_, -2) == strhead(RE, -2)]
```

Where $_ would be replaced with whatever the respective value of RES is. Is there a good way to do this?

I'm aware I could just write a for loop and do it like that, but it would be nice to have it in one line.

Comment: So, you just want to get "those elements in RES where the first two characters match [the first two characters of the first entry in RES]"?

If so, sort of; R is a vectorised language. When you perform an operation on a vector, like subsetting, what you're actually doing is performing that test on each /element/ of the vector. So you want something like:

RES <- RES[strhead(RES, -2) == strhead(RES[1],-2)]

Comment: As a general principle, though, VARIABLE NAMES IN ALL CAPS are hard to read, and I'd suggest avoiding them.

Comment: RES <- RES[strhead(RES, -2) == strhead(RES[1],-2)]
Yes, that would work perfectly. I can't believe I forgot I could do that :P thanks. If you post as an answer I'll mark it correct.

The strhead function with an argument of -2 returns all but the last 2 letters, fyi, but that's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Done! And yep, I googled it :). Luckily the CRAN docs are replicated pretty widely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just want to get "those elements in RES where the first two characters match [the first two characters of the first entry in RES]"? If so, sort of; R is a vectorised language. When you perform an operation on a vector, like subsetting, what you're actually doing is performing that test on each /element/ of the vector. So you want something like:

```
RES <- RES[strhead(RES, -2) == strhead(RES[1],-2)]
```